# Problem with raising event on hoverin on <li>

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors, userscripts

I'm trying to select the element under the cursor so I can take its text. I'm trying this as an userscript. All went good but I have small problem with lists. The code below works fine:

```
$("*:not(html head body").css("border", "1px solid blue");
```

With this it selects all elements on the page. But when I try to bind it to mouseover and similar events it doesn't work well on Amazon.com for example. I saw that happens on a li tag. Here's my code:

```
$("*:not(html, head, body)").live('mouseenter mouseover hover', function(e) {
   $(this).css("border", "1px solid blue");
});
```

Here's the Amazon.com left menu part of the source - [click here](http://pastie.org/1633975)

Can someone tell me idea what event to use on a hover over a li element? Or maybe a better method to do what I'm doing. Thanks.

Comment: Why not specify the styles in a style sheet, where you don't need JS at all?  Mouseover events are so 90s.

Comment: Cause I need the text. The border just shows me on which element am I hovering.

Comment: http://jshint.com - The code check failed.
Errors:
Line 3: Expected ')' and instead saw ''.
Line 3: Missing semicolon. --- Maybe post an example on [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net)

Comment: Sorry, bad paste. But the problem still exists.

Comment: What, exactly, is the problem?   The code seems to operate about how you'd expect.  Provide a link to the target page and a detailed description of the malfunction, with a screenshot if necessary.

Comment: I tried it on Amazon.com. The left side menu is not highlighted. The submenus are, but the main is not and I have no idea why that happens.

Answer (score 2):

You're missing `);` at the end of that code block.